# Formato para números enteros en my Account magento

Tags: magento2

¿Cómo muestro los valores de las órdenes de compra sin los decimales?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que los muestre así `$23.747`

En el modulo shipping tambien quiero hacer este cambio
Cuando toma la ciudad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al finalizar la compra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer todo el formato esta separado para cada vista

Comment: Conoces [la pagina de Stack Exchange de Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @lois6b aunque es válida tu sugerencia, es posible que el nivel de inglés del OP no sea suficiente para preguntar en dicho sitio.

Comment: @shaz ya ... pero bueno, lo dejo caer.

Comment: Para lo del envío, simplemente busca su plantilla e intenta hacer lo mismo que planteé en la respuesta. Si dicha plantilla no utiliza ese método, entonces deberás buscar otro método para cambiar el formato, o publica una nueva pregunta para analizar el problema con más detalle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no siempre es necesario según el método que utilices, puede ser buena idea hacer una copia en tu template de `Magento_Sales/order/recent.phtml`, en el cual encontrarás esta línea:

```
<td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
```

En Magento 2.1.4 es la línea 42.

---

Puedes quitar los ceros de varias formas:

1. Usando `format_number()` o alguna otra función que permita jugar con la información entragada por `formatPrice()`. Esta es la opción más sencilla pero la menos recomendada.
2. Utilizar `formatPricePrecision()` en vez de `formatPrice()` para poder pasar los decimales deseados como parámetro.

   ```
   $_order->formatPricePrecision($_order->getGrandTotal(), 0)
   ```

   Esta es tal vez la mejor opción utilizando las herramientas de Magento.
3. Si la modificación fuera mucho más compleja que eliminar los decimales o si el resultado de la función anterior no es el esperado, tendrías que crear una "preference" que sobreescriba la clase correspondiente, o de una manera más "profesional", crear un plugin para extender su funcionalidad sin cambiar el comportamiento original.

Comment: Cambia en esa parte el formato de numer,o pero para el modulo que tengo de shipping no realiza ningun cambio. Que me puedes sugerir en este caso

Comment: Es un problema distinto en ese caso. Si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo con esa parte, sigo buscando solucionar la parte del shipping